# Xcode 5 and missing NSFoundationVersionNumber

Tags: xcode, macos, foundation

I have MacOS 10.8.5 and Xcode 5 but I can't find anywhere a `NSFoundationVersionNumber` higher than `NSFoundationVersionNumber10_7_4` (this is the highest value defined in `NSObjCRuntime.h`). Is there something wrong in my installation?

I have to say that `MacOSX10.8.sdk` is the only sdk in my `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/`

Comment: same here, so your install is probably okay, but I have no idea why they are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply NSLog out NSFoundationVersionNumber and you will get the version number for the OS you are currently running. apple have forgot to provide NSFoundationVersionNumber constants for both iOS 7, 10.8 and 10.9 :/

Comment: In OS X 10.10 header they forgot to define a version number. Also in AppKit. There is no constant defined with my values.